# automatically generate API for existing database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

Is there any way to automatically generate Rails API for existing database? I have mysql DB from php project and I need to generate REST API for it.

Answer (score 2):

using rails 4, you could use scaffold, taking care to keep the data models exactly like the old database (ie. same table and column names), then remove the migrations that are generated with the scaffold.

let's say you have a table called Posts, with columns: subject and body.

You could run:

```
rails g scaffold post subject:string body:text
```

Then remove the migration from db/migrate.

Now assuming you set up the rails app to access the database correctly via config/database.yml, you should have a json API all set up and ready to use, since rails scaffold generates index.json.jbuilder and show.json.jbuilder for each resource that you scaffold.

You might have to edit the application controller to allow external API requests, but this should only matter if you plan on POSTing to your API:

if you do need to POST, then change this line in the top of your app/controllers/application_controller.rb:

```
# Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
# For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
```

to this:

```
protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
```

GET requests should work without modifying the application controller.

Forgot to mention, to access these resources, you will use ?format=json as a parameter, so:

```
http://localhost:3000/posts?format=json
```

or

```
http://localhost:3000/posts/1?format=json
```

Will return the json response for all posts or a single post.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [AutomaticApiRest](https://github.com/GeekyTheory/Automatic-API-REST) [automaticapirest.info], This project was created by myself last year. Basically, this tool allows to create an API REST of your DB (MySQL) in seconds.

### Features

1. Creation a powerful API REST of your MySQL Data Base in Seconds.
2. Management of the API in situ, it is not neccesary an extra data base.
3. Private tables and fields.
4. Custom queries.

### Installation

1. Download the source or clone the repo.

   git clone https://github.com/GeekyTheory/Automatic-API-REST
2. Place it in `/var/www/YourWebPage/` (for Apache).
3. Open the file **config.php**  and complete all the fields with the server credencials.
4. Go to **domain.com/AutomaticaApiRest**

Answer (score 1):

There is a Node.js alternative in which you can use any SQL database(MySQL, MSSQL, SQL Server, Aurora, PostgreSQL, and SQLite). I'm one of the core committers of that project.

Install the CLI tool([xc-cli)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xc-cli) globally from npm using the following command:

```
npm install -g xc-cli
```

Then you can create the project simply using following command:

```
xc new <project_name>
```

*Note : It would prompt for database connection details, just enter the connection details and it would do the rest of the code generation. And you have to install GUI tool to work the code generation(Download it from here: [https://github.com/xgenecloud/xc-desktop-app/releases)](https://github.com/xgenecloud/xc-desktop-app/releases)_)*

---

For more info refer GitHub repo: https://github.com/xgenecloud/xgenecloud

And for documentation refer: http://docs.xgenecloud.com/